# Running apache on android with termux and anlinux

Tags: android, apache, port, ulimit, termux

Following [this guide](https://medium.com/@HuffyPiet/how-i-set-up-apache2-web-server-with-termux-on-android-2d7e31aac63e)
I used termux and anlinux to install Ubuntu and apache2 on android. But when I run 'apachetcl start' I get this error:

```
root@localhost:~# apachectl start
/usr/sbin/apachectl:  99: ulimit: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)
Setting ulimit failed. See README.Debian for more information.
(13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down AH00015: Unable to open logs 
Action 'start' failed. The Apache error log may have more information.
```

Answer (score 1):

Just install termux from playstore
And the command `termux-setup-storage`
`apt update`
`apt install apache2`
`apachectl -k start`
and check http://127.0.01:8080 from favourite web browser

Answer (score 1):

For solve this problem, edit the file on `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` to this :

```
Listen 1024 # You can change the port from 80 to 1024 or greater
<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

Then save above code to `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`, you can edit that file using [Vim](https://www.vim.org) editor, [Nano](https://www.nano-editor.org) editor, or anything else.


After save the file, running apache2 using this command :

`sudo service apache2 restart`


Or :

`sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

**Note : If you not installed sudo, you can intall it by :** `apt install sudo`